# Dibujar un rectángulo en Camera Preview

Tags: android

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android y necesito que al abrirse la cámara se visualice una especie de rectangulo como en esta imagen https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoIF1.png No quiero que la foto se quede con lo que esté dentro del rectangulo, solo quiero que se vea para que el usuario centre la foto.

He leido que lo más común es hacer mi propia aplicación de cámara, pero no tengo tanto tiempo y recién estoy comenzando. Esto es el código que llevo de la clase inicial.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_eslyss);
    boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                        }
    });
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        bitmap2 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");            
    }
}
}
```

En esta otra pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894035/how-to-add-a-rectangular-overlay-in-a-camera-application explican como hacerlo y aunque creo la clase Box y hago la instancia, el rectangulo no aparece en la pantalla de la cámara, y por lo que leí, si debería funcionar. ¿Qué debo escribir para crear el dichoso rectángulo? Gracias