# Como es posible capturar una seccion desde la camara - Android

Tags: android

Hola buenas tardes estoy trabajando con el api de la camara "android.hardware.Camera" he logrado mostrar el preview de la camara dentro de mi aplicacion pero lo que en realidad preciso es realizar algo como esto, en pocas palabras solo capturar el area dentro de rectangulo.

[image: Imagen]

Comment: Hola Carlos, te saludo y te invito a realizar preguntas en base a [ask]. En cuanto a tu pregunta ¿has realizado investigación o un intento de capturar la sección de la pantalla?, en este caso sería complejo realizar lo que deseas ya que no se puede modificar el software de la camara, en mi opinion podrías intentar agregar una pantalla que simule solo mostrar una sección de la pantalla y realizar el corte de la imagen mediante código. ¿Platica sobre que deseas realizar con esto?

Comment: @Jorgesys Gracias  por la invitacion habia leido tu respuesta pero queria poder responder con tiempo. te invito a revisar por favor  este post [link]( https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/89888/dibujar-un-rect%C3%A1ngulo-en-camera-preview) donde creo haber formulado mejor la pregunta, gracias nuevamente por intentar ayudarme.